# Reduced density matrix for entangled state

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, density-operator

Given state $|\psi\rangle = \frac{|00\rangle + |01\rangle + |11\rangle}{\sqrt{3}}$ I was calculating the reduced density matrix $\rho^A$.
The given answer was $\rho^A = \frac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

But I am getting a different answer first, I calculated $|\psi\rangle \langle\psi|$ which was :

$ \frac{1}{3} [ |00\rangle \langle00| + |00\rangle \langle01|  + |00\rangle \langle11| + |01\rangle \langle00| + |01\rangle \langle01|  + |01\rangle \langle11| + |11\rangle \langle00| + |11\rangle \langle01|  + |11\rangle \langle11|] $

This alone was sufficient for me to prove that either the answer was wrong or my method is. since there is only 1 term which when reduced will give me $|0\rangle\langle0|$ but in the the given matrix there is a 2 at that position. Can someone explain me where my method is going wrong, or point out my numerical mistake.

Comment: ??? - There is |00><00| and |01><01|.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a $|\color{blue}0\rangle\langle\color{blue}0|$ term from both $|\color{blue}0\color{red}0\rangle \langle\color{blue}0\color{red}0|$ and $|\color{blue}0\color{red}1\rangle \langle\color{blue}0\color{red}1|$ for both $\langle\color{red}0|\color{red}0\rangle,\langle\color{red}1|\color{red}1\rangle=1$.